# How to use regex to remove all symbols but replace blank with '-'

Tags: python, regex, symbols

I know that with regex, for example

```
re.sub(r'[^\w]', '', string)
```

I can remove symbols from the string. But what I want now is to remove all other symbols but replace blank with '-'. Is there any way to do that?

For example,

```
string = "Felix's 3D's"
# I want it as "Felixs-3D"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace spaces with `-` then ignore and str.replace:

```
print(re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '',string).replace(" ","-"))
Felixs-3Ds
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a function to do the replacing:

```
def replace(match):
    return '-' if match.group().isspace() else ''

re.sub(r'[^\w]', replace, string)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> def replace(match):
...     return '-' if match.group().isspace() else ''
... 
>>> string = "Felix's 3D's"
>>> re.sub(r'[^\w]', replace, string)
'Felixs-3Ds'
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

> `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`
>
> ...
>
> If `repl` is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping
>   occurrence of pattern. The function takes a single match object
>   argument, and returns the replacement string.

So, `replace` will receive each match and return `'-'` if it is whitespace or `''` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
>>> st= "Felix's 3D's"
>>> re.sub(r'(\s)|[^a-zA-Z]', lambda m: '-' if m.group(0).isspace() else '', st)
'Felixs-Ds'
```

You can also do this without a regex:

```
>>> st.translate(None,"'").replace(' ','-')
'Felixs-3Ds'
```

And you can place all the target 'special' characters in the second argument to translate.